# I need to identify if the screen of my android phone is on or off

Tags: android, arduino

I need to identify if the screen of my android phone is on or off. And after identifying if it is on or off I need to send a bluetooth message to my arduino that will be paired with it. 1 = on and 0 = off.
Can someone help me do this, please?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about `arduino` but this maybe help you for check screen is off or on:

Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF and ACTION_SCREEN_ON check out for above broadcasts registration. [here](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/handling-screen-off-and-screen-on-intents/) you can find a good example.

And for send data to `arduino` from android device you can use below code :

```
private OutputStream outputStream;
private InputStream inStream;

private void init() throws IOException {
    BluetoothAdapter blueAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if (blueAdapter != null) {
        if (blueAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Set<BluetoothDevice> bondedDevices = blueAdapter.getBondedDevices();

            if(bondedDevices.size() > 0) {
                Object[] devices = (Object []) bondedDevices.toArray();
                BluetoothDevice device = (BluetoothDevice) devices[position];
                ParcelUuid[] uuids = device.getUuids();
                BluetoothSocket socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuids[0].getUuid());
                socket.connect();
                outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
                inStream = socket.getInputStream();
            }

            Log.e("error", "No appropriate paired devices.");
        } else {
            Log.e("error", "Bluetooth is disabled.");
        }
    }
}

public void write(String s) throws IOException {
    outputStream.write(s.getBytes());
}

public void run() {
    final int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int bytes = 0;
    int b = BUFFER_SIZE;

    while (true) {
        try {
            bytes = inStream.read(buffer, bytes, BUFFER_SIZE - bytes);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```